# Create custom buildpack un-authorized

Tags: terminal, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I defined as space and org admin and ive zip of buildpack which I've created and I want to executed and I got error

```
Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
```

Im in the folder which inside there is zip buildpack

```
C: 
 - myfolder
 -- custom_buildpack.zip
```

in the terminal im in

```
c:/myfolder/
```

And run the following command

```
cf create-buildpack custom_buildpack custom_buildpack.zip 12
```

and I got the error above , how can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to create or update build packs you must be a platform administrator.  That is the first bullet at [this link.](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html#roles)

> Admin is a user role that has been assigned the cloud_controller.admin scope in UAA. An admin user has permissions on all orgs and spaces and can perform operational actions using the Cloud Controller API.

It is not sufficient to be an org manager, space manager or space developer.

It is extremely unlikely that you will have sufficient access unless you have complete control of the CF installation.

If you do not have access you can use a custom build pack by specifying the `-b` argument to `cf push` or by setting `buildpack:` in your `manifest.yml` file.  The value of this argument should be a Git URL to your build pack.  Public hosting on Github or Bitbucket makes this easy, but you can use any service that's accessible from the staging environment of your CF installation.

Comment: Thanks 1+ so what is a platform admin , I thought that there is just org admin since im connecting to the org...can you explain please what is platform since i didnt heard this term befofe...

Comment: Org and space roles are managed and enforced by cloud controller.  A platform admin receives his or her permissions from UAA scopes.  As quoted from the docs above, a platform admin would have the `cloud_controller.admin` scope in UAA.  Every CF installation will have at least one platform administrator, but more can be added with the process here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/uaa-user-management.html#creating-admin-users